# for a in b.layers: The object is not iterable

Tags: python, loops, iteration, arcgis, iterable

I am trying to list all the feature services using the below code,

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
gis = GIS(url='https://pythonapi.playground.esri.com/portal', username='arcgis_python', password='amazing_arcgis_123')

items = gis.content.search(query="", item_type="Feature Service")

some_list = []

for b in items:
    print(b.layers)
    print(b)
    for a in b.layers:
         if a.properties['name'] == 'WETTBEWERBER':
              some_list.append(a)
```

but I get this error, what am I doing wrong ?? Any insights will be helpful.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/untitled/Test/Test maps.py", line 14, in <module>

    for a in b.layers:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I get the printed results as follows, but if I take one of the printed result URLs and tried to get that layer by changing the name according to the printed URL, I do not get any results.

```
F:\ArcGISPro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\python.exe "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/untitled/Test/Test maps.py"

[<FeatureLayer url:"https://maps.com/server/rest/services/Hosted/sd/FeatureServer/0">]

<Item title:"sd" type:Feature Layer Collection owner:dafsa>

[<FeatureLayer url:"https://maps.com/server/rest/services/Hosted/CC/FeatureServer/0">]

<Item title:"CC" type:Feature Layer Collection owner:sajd57d>

[<FeatureLayer url:"https://maps.com/server/rest/services/MD/FeatureServer/0">]

<Item title:"MD" type:Feature Layer Collection owner:dasjc6>

[<FeatureLayer url:"https://maps.com/server/rest/services/Hosted/ring/FeatureServer/0">]

<Item title:"ring" type:Feature Layer Collection owner:dashk56>
```

For example, if I take the first URL and open my portal I can see the Feature containing a layer with its name 'WETTBEWERBER' but if the results do not show anything.

Comment: You get this error because `b.layers` is `None`  try debugging and inspect `b` when this error is raised.

Comment: I have used the print for b and b.layers it prints the values, after the if clause it's not proceeding. What can be the issue ??

Comment: Where did you put `print(b.layers)`? It should be right between the first and the second `for` lines.

Comment: @9769953, Yes the "print(b.layers)" is between the first and second "for" lines and prints out the layers

Comment: If all your print statements show actual values (iterables), but you still get this error, then your problem may not be reproducible.

Comment: I'd like to see the output of `print(items)` before the first `for` and `print(b)` between the two `for` statements. Please add it to your question. I suspect at least one of the items does not have layers.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect one or more of the items does not have layers, which would cause this error. You should try checking and skipping those items.

```py
for b in [item for item in items if item.layers is not None]:
    for a in b.layers:
         if a.properties['name'] == 'WETTBEWERBER':
              some_list.append(a)
```

---

I have written an example to illustrate the issue:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Item:
    name: str
    layers: list


items = [Item("a", None), Item("b", ["l1", "l2"])]

for item in items:
    for layer in item.layers:
        print(layer)
```

Here, we get the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` because one of the items have `None` for property `layers`. The correction is to skip those.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Item:
    name: str
    layers: list


items = [Item("a", None), Item("b", ["l1", "l2"])]

for item in [item for item in items if item.layers is not None]:
    for layer in item.layers:
        print(layer)
```

yielding:

```
l1
l2
```

---

Also, as @aaron correctly points out, `for a in b.layers or ()` or `for a in b.layers or []` work too. They are even more terse, and fine in this case. In some cases, being explicit with a None check is important, but not so much here.

```py
for item in items:
    for layer in item.layers or []:
        print(layer)
```

Comment: `for a in b.layers or ():` is more succinct, though `if b.layers is not None: for a in b.layers:` is a better programming style.

Comment: Yeah, I goofed. Pretty sure I fixed it.

Comment: @theherk, I have updated the question with the print results, I have used the one of the printed results name to get the list even though nothing is retured.

Comment: @Aravinth, I'm not sure what you meant by using one of the printed results. Nevertheless you didn't print the full list of items before both loops. That is the critical bit, because based on my suspicion, the length of that list will be longer than the number printed before the error is raised.

Comment: @theherk, I have used one of the printed results to check the code, that if the URL is printed, I can use the printed URLs layer to list out feature names so that I can validate it. Yes the printed result is longer I did not post everything here, I have changed according to your answer and tried to run it after that only the urls of the first 2 print functions are listed not the some_list.append(a) it returns empty.

Comment: Okay. It makes sense that you it works when there is a layer url. Those items have the layers property. It makes sense that the list is longer than those printing, because it gets to one that has layers as None and raises the error. I'm not following the current state though. Can you post your current code and current output? Maybe as an addendum in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
some_list = [[a for a in b.layers if a.properties['name'] == 'WETTBEWERBER'] \
for b in items if b.layers]
```

Test using this logic:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Item:
    st:str
    layers:list

prop1 = {"properties":{
    "name" : "l1"
}}

prop2 = {"properties":{
    "name" : "l1"
}}

prop3 = {"properties":{
    "name" : "l3"
}}

items = [Item('a', None),Item('b', [prop1]),Item('c',[prop2]),Item('d', None),Item('e', [prop3])]

lst = [[a for a in b.layers if a['properties']['name'] == 'l1'] \
for b in items if b.layers]
print(lst)
```

Alternatively, you could just add -> `if b.layers is Not None` after `for b in items`